# What's the difference between Virtually Indexed Physically tagged and Virtually Indexed and Virtually Tagged Paging?

Tags: memory, indexing, operating-system, paging

Also, state if there are any other methods for Indexing and Tagging ?

Comment: Where did you get those terms?

Answer (score 18):

The CPU cache is divided in *cache lines*, which have a fixed size (usually 64 bytes). In general, we can say that each *cache line* is identified by the address of the memory it refers to (with the last 6 bits discarded because they refer to an offset *inside* the cache line).

To make the lookup faster the address is split in two parts: **index** and **tag**. The **index** addresses a *set* of cache lines which position is known: accessing a *set* is really fast. Inside an *N-way associative set* you have N cache lines, in no particular order, which will be identified using a **tag**.

Now we said that **tag** and **index** are portions of the memory address, but what type of address? Physical or virtual?

In theory you can have any combination of *physically indexed* (PI), *physically tagged* (PT), *virtually indexed* (VI), and *virtually tagged* (VT).
Each combination has its pros and cons. In general, we can say that using physical addresses has the drawback of having to wait for the virtual address to be translated (which can be expensive in case of a TLB miss), on the other hand, using virtual addresses, while faster, can cause coherency problems because multiple virtual addresses can map to the same physical address and mappings can change over time requiring cache flushes.

For these reasons, PIPT is used only for *slow* cache (e.g. L2/L3), VIVT is rarely used, PIVT is almost never used and VIPT is used for *fast* (and small) cache.

The advantage of using VIPT is that, while the lookup can start in parallel with the address translation (and so it's faster than PIPT), it uses the physical address for the last part of the lookup so, with a properly chosen size for the **index**, it can prevent coherency problems.
The correct size for the **index** depends on the *page size*: translations between virtual and physical address is made at *page level*, if the **index** is chosen in such a way that it always refers to the offset of the *cache line* inside the *page* it won't make any difference if we are using a physical address or a virtual address. Unfortunately this limits the size of the cache, hence the reason why it is used only for fast and small cache (e.g. L1).